# "The soup" meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I read [Post Office](https://books.google.com/books?id=XjQ5zlnQ8ZcC&pg=PA14&dq=%22The+soup+was+a+bullneck+named+Jonstone.%22) by Charles Bukovski and I came across this sentence:

> **The soup** was a bullneck named Jonstone.

Who could help me to understand this soup meaning

Comment: Thank you for linking to the source.  That lets me find more context.  You can help answer your question by giving more context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the third time "soup" has been used in this context in this novel. The narrator is a temporary Christmas postman and he says:

> They only gave you a block or two and if you managed to finish ... the soup would give you another.

then later

> ... I was—a substitute mail carrier... the soup was easy and I strolled around doing a block or two...

and finally, your example "the soup was a bullneck named Johnson".

So a "soup" is a person, this person can be tough (a bullneck) or "easy". And if you finish your work early, this person can give you extra work.

So "soup" must mean "*superintendent*" or "supervisor", I.e the person in charge of the mail carriers.  It is an abbreviation, but not one that I've seen before. However, the meaning is clear enough in context.

Comment: Normally this would be spelled "supe". Perhaps the OP got this from an audiobook and didn't see it in print?

Comment: @Beanluc It seems to be the same in the print edition, based on the Google Books link from the OP.

Comment: So, any reason behind why "soup" is linked to "superintendent"?